# SQL Server to MySql conversion - schema vs. database question

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2008, schema

All,

We are evaluating MySql as a lower cost alternative to SQL server for our smaller clients in a shared hosting environment.  I am still foggy on how we would migrate some of the particulars such as table/scalar value functions, sql jobs, etc, but I will post specifics in another thread.  I do, however, have a fundamental question about databases vs. schemas in MySql.

Currently, our SQL server instance has multiple databases with multiple schemas in each.  For example:

**Database (schemas...)**
====================
Client1Database (dbo, web)
Client2Database (dbo, web, schema3)
Client3Database (dbo, schema2)

In my sample MySql instance, it appears as though the top level objects are schemas, not databases.  But the "schemas" have database icons next to them and, in our case, a "schema" is listed as part of the connection string in our .NET apps.

So I guess I just have a few clarification questions as to how to perceive the schemas/databases in MySql...

1. Can the top level objects in a MySql instance be considered schemas if a database consists of multiple schemas, or a single schema "database".
2. In the scenario above, would I create a separate instance for each client, flatten the individual client databases to a single schema and keep the three clients in the same instance, or some other method that is escaping me?  Is there a benefit, security, clarity, or otherwise to one approach over another?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: What is the size of the DB of your "small client" ?

Comment: Shared environment would be 3-5 clients.  Databases range from about 50-500MB each.  For the most part, the client databases can be consolidated into one schema, though currently a few of them have more than one schema in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I would advice you or anyone to avoid using MySQL, there's a lot of free RDBMS available, my favorite being PostgreSQL which in my view is way better. Also, your requirement being quite small, it shouldn't be a problem using SQL Server Express, although I understand that shared hosting can be limiting your options there. You (hopefully) already have figured this out, but I'll try to answer your questions anyway...

1. Basically MySQL doesn't have schemas, only databases (which are called catalogs in the standard). Some years ago they decided to add the keyword `SCHEMA` as an alias for `DATABASE`. There's plans laying around to add the concept of schemas, but I wouldn't count on it being implemented anytime soon.
2. It mostly depend on how you're using databases vs schemas in your current setup. In most cases, I would think it's better to keep those databases into a single instance to simplify administration tasks.

P.S.: It would be great to have an update on how you resolved this problem in the end.